# Why is IE7 cutting off the bottom of list items with this CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

Hey I have a really annoying IE7 bug that I am trying to work out. The bottom of list items are getting cut off:

**IE7**
[Image in IE7 http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/9363/picture16u.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/9363/picture16u.png)

**Firefox**
[Image in Firefox http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/246/picture17lk.png](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/246/picture17lk.png)

Here is the CSS:

```
/* begin buttons */

ul.buttons { /* general settings */                       
margin-left: 0;                                              
margin-bottom: 0em;                                              
margin-right: 0;                                              
margin-top: .0em;                                              
float: left;                                              
height: 23px;                                             
text-shadow: 0px 0px;                       
text-align: left; /* set to left, right or center */ /* set margins as desired */ /* set font as desired */
list-style-type: none; /* THIRD number must change with respect to padding-top (X) below */
}

ul.buttons li { /* do not change */
display: inline;
height: 35px;  
}

ul.buttons li img {
margin-right: 7px;
}

body#tab1 li.tab1, body#tab2 li.tab2, body#tab3 li.tab3, body#tab4 li.tab4 { /* settings for selected tab */
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /* set border color to page background color */
background-color: #fff; /* set background color to match above border color */
}

body#tab1 li.tab1 a, body#tab2 li.tab2 a, body#tab3 li.tab3 a, body#tab4 li.tab4 a { /* settings for selected tab link */
background-color: #fff; /* set selected tab background color as desired */
color: #000; /* set selected tab link color as desired */
position: relative;
top: 1px;
padding-top: 4px; /* must change with respect to padding (X) above and below */
}

ul.buttons li a { /* settings for all tab links */                                 
border-bottom-color: #4c9a01;                                                                  
border-bottom-width: 1px;                                                                  
border-bottom-style: solid;                                                                  
letter-spacing: .1em;                                                                  
color: white;                                                                  
padding-left: 8px;                                 
padding-bottom: 4px;                                 
padding-right: 8px;                                 
padding-top: 5px;                                 
font-size: .75em; /* set padding (tab size) as desired; FIRST number must change with respect to padding-top (X) above */ /* set border COLOR as desired; usually matches border color specified in #tabnav */
background-color: #94c909; /* set unselected tab background color as desired */ /* set unselected tab link color as desired */
margin-right: 8px; /* set additional spacing between tabs as desired */
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and the html:

```
<ul class="buttons">
  <li class="tab1"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li class="tab2"><a href="index2.html">My Leases</a></li>
  <li class="tab3"><a href="index3.html">Guide</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have googled this but I can't seem to find a solution, any ideas?

Comment: Ooops, I forgot the screenshot in firefox:

Firefox: http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/246/picture17lk.png

Comment: @Thomas: I added your pictures inline for you, saves people having to do seperate navigations to compare.

Comment: A snippet of the html would be helpful too...

Comment: Here is the HTML:
<ul class="buttons"> 
      <li class="tab1"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li> 
      <li class="tab2"><a href="index2.html">My Leases</a></li> 
      <li class="tab3"><a href="index3.html">Guide</a></li>
     </ul>

Comment: Thanks. p.s. it would be better to put the html in the answer so that it formats nicely.

Comment: Not allowed to- with the addittion of the image, my status is too low to edit a post with mulitple images - sorry.

Comment: @Thomas: i've done it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `li` elements are cut off by the `ul` element's height (23px):

```
ul.buttons { /* general settings */                        
margin-left: 0;                                               
margin-bottom: 0em;                                               
margin-right: 0;                                               
margin-top: .0em;                                               
float: left;                                               
height: 23px;  /* <--- here */                                             
text-shadow: 0px 0px;                        
text-align: left; /* set to left, right or center */ /* set margins as desired */ /* set font as desired */ 
list-style-type: none; /* THIRD number must change with respect to padding-top (X) below */ 
}
```

Most likely, the default `overflow` value differs in IE and Firefox.  Can you increase the `ul` height to the `35px` height of your `li` elements?

---

**rohancragg** commented with a good suggestion of using a CSS reset file to normalize browser CSS defaults - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

---

I've just spotted the `display: inline;` on your `li` elements.  `height` is ignored for `inline` elements and you should use `inline-block` instead.

Comment: Same answer as me but better. I'd add - when defaults differ between broswers then a good technique is to set them all to the same set of defaults using the css reset technique http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Yup, I have tried all of the different overflow values on ul.buttons

Comment: If it helps you can check out the bug (along with a few others I have yet to sort out) on the actual page:

http://current-post.com/qmail/email.html

Comment: @Thomas: I actually spotted what the cause of the issue might be while I was adding the HTML to your question - see my latest update.

Comment: @Thomas: unfortunately I can't verify my answer because my IE developer tools aren't working - grr!

Comment: This is getting really really complicated but basically, when I add inline-block, some of the li space is recovered except for the last 5px or so... I guess there must be a couple of issues here -

Comment: @Thomas: lol at least we're getting somewhere.  Have you tried `overflow: visible` on your `li` elements?

Comment: Yeah and I set the ul heights up to 35 as well.

Comment: @Thomas: just got my developer tools working.  I checked and it's actually the child `a` element that's not the correct height (because `a` elements are inline by default).  I was able to fix it by setting `display: block;` to the `a` elements.

Comment: Wow, I think you just saved me an ulcer. Thanks Andy!

Comment: Just glad to help. You wouldn't believe how simple my developer tools problem was!

Answer (score 1):

First, install [IE Development Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en). It is like Fire Bug and will let you change CSS on the Fly.

Second, change the CSS in the live site to find the problem.

Third, change the CSS and test in Firefox. If it still looks fine in Firefox you are done else create an IF IE statement in your CSS like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I have a seperate IE7 stylesheet, thats what I have been playing with- 
you guys were right, I didn't need the height definition on UL, however it still doesn't fix the clipping issue.

Answer (score 0):

First guess is that one browser is ignoring the height of the `ul` and using the height of the `li`. why do you need to specify a smaller height on the `ul.button`s than that of `ul.buttons li`?